# MOQ unit test - Return type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am very new to MOQ and have an issue I cannot solve. I have the following code I am testing (I am testing first one - **ValidateInputBankFile**):

```
    #region Constructor

    private readonly IErrorRepository _errorRepository;
    private readonly IFileSystem _fileSystem;
    public IP_BankInfoDeserializer(IErrorRepository errorRepository, IFileSystem fileSystem)
    {
        _errorRepository = errorRepository;
        _fileSystem = fileSystem;
    }
    #endregion

    public IP_BankInfo ValidateInputBankFile(string sPath, App.BankType bankType)
    {
        if (!_fileSystem.FileExists((sPath)))
            return null;

        //first retrieve representative bank info
        var tmpInfo = DeserializeBankInfo(bankType);

        if (tmpInfo == null)
            return null;//Does not exist

        return tmpInfo;
    }

    public IP_BankInfo DeserializeBankInfo(App.BankType bankType)
    {
        if (!IsFileCorrect(bankType))
            return null;

        IP_BankInfo info = new IP_BankInfo();

        using (var stream = new StreamReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + sFolder + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar +
                                              bankType.ToString() + ".xml"))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(IP_BankInfo));
            try
            {
                info = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as IP_BankInfo;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                info = null;
            }
        }

        return info;
    }
```

This is my test method:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ValidateInputBank_ExistingPath_ExistingBank()
    {
        Mock<IFileSystem> fileSystem = new Mock<IFileSystem>();
        fileSystem.Setup(n => n.FileExists(null)).Returns(true);

        Mock<IP_BankInfoDeserializer> mocSerializer = new Mock<IP_BankInfoDeserializer>();
        mocSerializer.Setup(n => n.DeserializeBankInfo(App.BankType.UniCredit)).Returns(new Models.IP_BankInfo());

        var result = mocSerializer.Object.ValidateInputBankFile(null, App.BankType.UniCredit);

        //Assert.AreEqual(serializer.Object.ValidateInputBankFile(null, App.BankType.UniCredit), new Models.IP_BankInfo());
    }
```

What I am trying to do, is to avoid call to **DeserializeBankInfo**, return new `IP_BankInfo` and so that I can check it under my final assert stage.

The problem is that my **var result** always returns null. I don't understand what am I doing wrong?

Also it fails on the following code `mocSerializer.Setup(n => n.DeserializeBankInfo(App.BankType.UniCredit)).Returns(()=>null);`, yet I am passing correct parameters.

Comment: You only appear to have a mocked version of your class in your test - you should be constructing an instance of _the actual class_ you want to test, passing in mocked objects of anything that _that class requires_ so when it calls those methods during the test, you're in complete control of the information passed back to the class under test.

Comment: I can create instance of `IP_BankInfoDeserializer`, yet when I call `ValidateInputBankFile` I don't want it to call `DeserializeBank` as it makes calls to XMLSerializer, but directly return what I want. The problem is I don't know how to bypass that call

Comment: You may need to introduce another layer then, and pass in an interface responsible for talking to the underlying storage to this class.  At the moment, the unit you're testing (the class) is responsible for accessing the disk within `DeserializeBankInfo`, so if you're testing this unit, you're going to test the disk access as part of it.  If you want it to be separate, you'll have to separate it out into it's own unit.  Unit testing doesn't necessarily mean testing of individual functions - a unit is more often the entire class.

Comment: On a completely unrelated note - you might want to take a look at [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) - would clean up the stream reader construction a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To answer your question**

> The problem is that my var result always returns null. I don't understand what am I doing wrong?

`ValidateInputBankFile` is never setup and you use loose mocks, therefore it will return null.

Use Strict mocks by passing MockBehavior.Strict in the constructor of your mock and you will have an exception telling you that your method was not setup.

Apply a Setup to return an appropriate value on that mock for the `ValidateInputBankFile` method and it will behave correctly.

**A word of advice**

You are calling methods on a mocked object from within your test :

```
var result = mocSerializer.Object.ValidateInputBankFile(null, App.BankType.UniCredit);
```

As a rule of thumb, you should never call method on a `xxx.Object.MyMethod()`

the reason why you should not do that is because you're basically just calling your "arrange" part of the test.

I feel like I need to ask you what you are trying to achieve by doing so, because you're basically just *testing your test*.

Answer (score 0):

Personally to me it looks like you are attempting to test your class but as the same time mock it so that not all of the class runs. **I** see this as incorrect, effectively how do you know that the deserialisation code is working correctly?

If your answer is another test where you mock other functionality in your class I would reply saying that you need to abstract out the deserialisation functionality of the `BankInfo` into another interface/class that you can mock and inject this into your `IBankInfoValidator`.

This means that you are splitting out your validation from the deserialisation of the object, this will help both in testing and maintainability/extensibility in the future if your use case changes.

Personally I'd scrap your tests just now, start looking to abstract out the deserialisation of your object and then think about testing it as separate classes.